# Refactoring && multiple flush() && manual transaction

Tags: php, symfony, optimization, transactions, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor my code in my controller.

I've got many treatment with lot of `->persist()` and one `->flush()` at the end.

It's good but I want to refactor all my treatments in functions for more lisibility and reuse in other context.

In my different functions I must `->flush()` to write. (To reuse in other context)

I known it's better to flush at the end of the treatment.

But if I use a manual transaction like this :

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $this->function1();
        $this->function2();
        $this->function3();
         $em->getConnection()->commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $em->getConnection()->rollback();
        $em->close();
        //écriture de l'exception ans les logs 
        throw $e;
    }

function function1(){
    ....
    $em->persist($object1);
    $em->flush();
}

function function2(){
    ....
    $em->persist($object2);
    $em->flush();
}

function function3(){
    ....
    $em->persist($object3);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Is it optimize and send one time at the end, like with one `->flush()` ?

Thanks for your help